# Hangman Code Issue (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple hangman program in java for a school assignment and I have it working for the most part. The main problem I have with it is that it keeps printing out the hidden word twice. It also only goes through and asks the user to enter an word 8 times when it should be 15 times. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
// Its in a separate method.
public static void application1() throws Exception {
    // Tells the user about the game.
    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!");
    System.out.println("Please try to guess the word within 15 letters.");

    String option = "";

    // Creates a array of all the phrases.
    String answer[] = new String[20];
    answer[0] = "computer";
    answer[1] = "radio";
    answer[2] = "calculator";
    answer[3] = "teacher";
    answer[4] = "bureau";
    answer[5] = "police";
    answer[6] = "geometry";
    answer[7] = "president";
    answer[8] = "subject";
    answer[9] = "country";
    answer[10] = "environment";
    answer[11] = "classroom";
    answer[12] = "animals";
    answer[13] = "province";
    answer[14] = "month";
    answer[15] = "politics";
    answer[16] = "puzzle";
    answer[17] = "instrument";
    answer[18] = "kitchen";
    answer[19] = "language";

    do {
        // Creates a random number to choose which word to choose from.
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 20 + 0);

        StringBuffer word = new StringBuffer("");

        // This makes the unknown word as long as the actual word.
        for (int i = 0; i < answer[rand].length(); i++) {
            word.append("_");
        }

        System.out.println(word);

        char input = ' ';

        // This is where it checks the input and replaces the letters.
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            input = (char) System.in.read();

            for (int j = 0; j < answer[rand].length(); j++) {
                if (input == answer[rand].charAt(j)) {
                    word.setCharAt(j, input);
                }
            }

            // This is where the hidden word get printed twice.
            System.out.println(word);
        }

        // Asks the user if they want to restart the application.
        System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
        option = input();

    } while (option.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
}
```

Comment: input(); why did you call input()?

Comment: The input() was a separate method where it got a user input.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Scanner` to get your input.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();
char input = line.charAt(0);
```

I think `System.in.read();` is returning the entered character and the enter key. (the \n char).

That makes your cycle run twice for each input, printing two times and looking like it only accepts 8 chars.

Comment: Oh, so the System.in.read(); was the problem. I tried the scanner and it worked, thank you.

Comment: Good to know it worked. Don't forget to accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: I tried an if statement saying if word.equals(answer[rand]) then print " you got it" and then asks if you would like to ry again but it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: `word` is a `StringBuffer`, and you are comparing it to a `String`. Try `if (word.toString().equals(answer[rand]))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (word.equals(answer[rand])) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the word!");

    // Asks the user if they want to restart the application.
    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
    option = input();
}
else if (i == 14) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you did not guess the word.");

    // Asks the user if they want to restart the application.
    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? (Y/N)");
    option = input();

    // Returns to the main menu.
    menu();
}
```

This doesn't recognize the word is correct.